# ¿como se puede hacer en c un programa que te de los números del 1 al 10 desordenados?

Tags: c

básicamente el código funciona así, la función aleatorio está anteriormente creada y genera un numero aleatorio hasta el 10, si este numero es 0 vuelve a repetir el proceso hasta que deje de serlo con la función while:

```
int aleatorio(){
time_t t;
srand(time(NULL));
int r;
r=rand()%10+1;


return r;


}
```

después de definir aleatorio() pasa a hacer esto

```
 for (i=0;i<10;i++){
 p[i]=aleatorio();//genera un numero aleatorio(entre 1 y 10) que lo asigna al 
valor de p[i]
if(i!=0){//excluye el primer paso
for(j=0;j<i;j++){
        while (p[j]==p[i]){//chequea si el valor generado se ha usado anteriormente
                p[i]=aleatorio();
        }

}
}
printf("%d \n",p[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Problema

Tu error se encuentra en la verificación que haces para ver si el número está repetido. En la siguiente parte de tu código, solo se genera un nuevo valor que no sea igual al actual en cuestión, pero este nuevo número no se valida contra el resto del array.

```c
while (p[j]==p[i]){//chequea si el valor generado se ha usado anteriormente
                p[i]=aleatorio();
        }
```

## Solución

Cambiando la parte de verificación de tu código, una posible solución podría ser la siguiente.

```c
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        p[i] = aleatorio(); //genera un numero aleatorio(entre 1 y 10) que lo asigna al valor de p[i]

        if (i != 0) //excluye el primer paso
        {
            j = 0;
            while (j < i){
                if (p[i]==p[j]){
                    p[i] = aleatorio();
                    j = 0; // Reset para evaluar todo el array nuevamente
                }
                else j++;
            }
        }
        printf ("%d \n", p[i]);
    }
```

Aunque esto ocasiona que los tiempos de ejecución no sean siempre los mismos.

## Alternativa

A continuación te dejo una solución alternativa que puede resolver tu problema de obtener una lista de números del 1 al 10, desordenados y sin repetirse. Aquí se hace uso de la función `rand()` que genera un número aleatorio. Esta función puede ser reemplazada por tu función `aleatorio()`, sin problemas.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() {
    int i, p[10], temp, randomIndex;

    // Primero genera la lista de 10 numeros (ordenados)
    for(i=0;i<10;i++) {
        p[i] = i+1;
    }

    // Mezcla los numeros
    srand ( time(NULL) ); //Semilla para rand()
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        temp = p[i];
        randomIndex = rand() % 10; // Indice aleatorio (acotado entre 0 y 9)
        p[i] = p[randomIndex];
        p[randomIndex] = temp;
    }

    // Imprime array
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("%d,",p[i]);
    }
}
```